# New MATE install, old home partition and drive not accessible

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, home-directory

I've seen a lot of similar questions but not quite like my situation.

Clarification: Ubuntu MATE for both old and new, switching installs from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS

I have my setup as SSD for Windows/Ubuntu MATE and two HDDs for storage - one for windows, the other one set as /home for ubuntu.

I recently did a fresh OS install on SSD for both windows and linux.

During setup, I chose 'other', and set the SSD linux partition as /, and mark the proper partition on the HDD to set as /home, *without formatting* which has my old config, files, storage, etc. **(Extra question - should i have set the entire drive as /home?)**

On boot, there was an issue getting past the login screen which I was able to resolve by livedisk and setting automount through gparted (since it didn't automount, it didn't have a /home to boot into)

While I can freely use ubuntu now, none of my old /home settings show - empty desktop, empty folders, etc.  Since setting the automount it doesn't show the HDD as an external storage drive which was desired and same as my old setup.

When I check via live disk it's clearly flagged as /home and there's definitely data still there, but when I go to the folders under my old home folder, it's empty.  Oddly enough,  I'm able to read but not write into the second profile on my linux partition.  The main profile shows the default desktop, music, pictures, downloads folders, but are all empty.  Booting into livedisk does not give access to these files.  The space available indicates that the data is all still there.

I'm using the same usernames (different PC name) and passwords.  I've tried chown (but willing to take more advice).  I'm thinking that during the install something went wonky and set up a new home instead of taking on the old one properly.  Any idea how to set?

attempts:

1. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=310360 and
   https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=310511

Followed these instructions, furthest I got was automounting and being able to boot into linux.

2. `chown user:user /dev/sda2 -R` (proper home partition)

had no effect.

Possible leads:

1. [This looks promising but it might overwrite my old home folder?](https://www.tecmint.com/move-home-directory-to-new-partition-disk-in-linux/)
2. [Option number two from catweazel on seems the most promising lead I'm willing to try but an ominous no reply from OP](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=290653)

requested:

```
sudo blkid:

/dev/sdb5: UUID="64afd68d-30b8-4e9e-848e-6bc24b721026" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="52baa0ed-f432-4be7-ba30-b527251c7726"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="1d7eb1f8-4972-4c20-9c6e-765afbf61eb1"
/dev/sda2: UUID="3571db23-f246-49d0-93bd-11515ec34bb8" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="677ba167-e2c6-4c1c-b9bc-461f2f3f5836"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="4E81-5D64" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="51e874a2-6064-4401-ad7f-d47a55a735e2"
/dev/sdb2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="1453ce7e-6045-46dc-8aa5-3e32e25aed94"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="2EF28285F28250CF" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="45075ffc-056a-461f-b5bb-8aa8907fd080"
/dev/sdb4: UUID="5026BEB626BE9D02" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e1dc02de-c48b-4657-b00e-2daef098f383"


mount:
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=8124300k,nr_inodes=2031075,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1633496k,mode=755)
/dev/sdb5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=825)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1885.snap on /snap/core18/1885 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1880.snap on /snap/core18/1880 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_9607.snap on /snap/snapd/9607 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/ubuntu-mate-welcome_559.snap on /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/559 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_8542.snap on /snap/snapd/8542 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/software-boutique_54.snap on /snap/software-boutique/54 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/ubuntu-mate-welcome_539.snap on /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/539 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sdb1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda2 on /home type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1633492k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)

fstab:


 # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=64afd68d-30b8-4e9e-848e-6bc24b721026 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=4E81-5D64  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda2 during installation
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=3571db23-f246-49d0-93bd-11515ec34bb8 /home ext4 auto,rw,user,exec 0 2

lsblk

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop1    7:1    0  55.3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop2    7:2    0    31M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9607
loop3    7:3    0  14.9M  1 loop /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/559
loop4    7:4    0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop5    7:5    0    16K  1 loop /snap/software-boutique/54
loop6    7:6    0  14.9M  1 loop /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/539
sda      8:0    0   5.5T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   128M  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    0   5.5T  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0 894.3G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2   8:18   0    16M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0 866.9G  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0   505M  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0  26.8G  0 part /
```

Comment: After boot MATE OS run as root; `blkid`, `mount`, `cat /etc/fstab` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Hi @guiverc - sorry it's moving from an Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Also, if you are referring to your SSD then no, you should not have set the entire SSD as `/home` and you should set `/home` to the correct partition if there is more than one partition your HDD drive. I may be wrong but it sounds like you did everything correct during the first installation but sometimes things get mixed up and also sometimes the drive numbers like `/dev/sda2` change as well. Because of this, it will help to post the output of the following command `lsblk`

Comment: @mariaczi - edited, thank you

Comment: @mchid - edited, thank you